# using pypubsub & wxpython to transfer data between windows getting TypeError:

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, pypubsub

I am trying to pass data between two wxpython windows using PyPubSub.  Below I have pared the code down the the basics. What I am getting when I fill in the data in the textcntrl on the main window  and hit the button to pass it to the second window (CoordFrame) I am getting the following error-

TypeError: sendMessage() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Every example I can find shows passing two parameters in the pub.sendMessage;  which is what I think I'm doing.  What is the 3rd parameter being passed, where does it come form and how do I stop it?  I have tried various combinations of arguments, and datatypes including binary.

'''

```
from pubsub import pub
import wx

class MainFrame (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (200,200))
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)

class CoordFrame (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(CoordFrame, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (200,200))
        self.panel = CoordPanel(self)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MainPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    
        self.tbxNewMap = wx.TextCtrl(self, id=1001, pos=(20,20), size = (50,20) ,style = wx.TE_CENTER|wx.TE_NOHIDESEL|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        vsizer.Add(self.tbxNewMap)

        self.btnEnterNewMap = wx.Button(self, id=1002, label = "New Data", pos = (20,80), size = (80,40))
        vsizer.Add(self.btnEnterNewMap,0,wx.EXPAND)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButtonNewMap, id=1002)

    def onButtonNewMap(self,event):
        temp = self.tbxNewMap.GetValue()
        pub.sendMessage("coord_listener", temp)
        coordframe = CoordFrame(None,"Entry")
        coordframe.Show()

class CoordPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CoordPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pub.subscribe(self.coord_listener, "coord_listener")

        self.tbxNewMapNumber = wx.TextCtrl(self, id=1000, pos=(20,20), size = (50,20), style = wx.TE_CENTER|wx.TE_NOHIDESEL|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        vsizer.Add(self.tbxNewMapNumber)
        
    def coord_listener(self, message):
        newmapnum = message
        self.tbxNewMapNumber.SetValue(newmapnum)
        self.tbxNewMapNumber.Refresh()


class GMDash(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.mainframe = MainFrame(parent = None, title = "Dashboard")
        self.mainframe.Show()
        return True

app = GMDash()
app.MainLoop()
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

Use a named argument in the call to `sendmessage` and you'll need to register the listener `before` sending the message, not after, as you are currently doing.

See below:

```
from pubsub import pub
import wx

class MainFrame (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (200,200))
        self.panel = MainPanel(self)

class CoordFrame (wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(CoordFrame, self).__init__(parent, title = title, size = (200,200))
        self.panel = CoordPanel(self)


class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MainPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    
        self.tbxNewMap = wx.TextCtrl(self, id=1001, pos=(20,20), size = (50,20) ,style = wx.TE_CENTER|wx.TE_NOHIDESEL|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        vsizer.Add(self.tbxNewMap)

        self.btnEnterNewMap = wx.Button(self, id=1002, label = "New Data", pos = (20,80), size = (80,40))
        vsizer.Add(self.btnEnterNewMap,0,wx.EXPAND)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onButtonNewMap, id=1002)
    #Register the subscrption *before* sending the message
        self.coordframe = CoordFrame(None,"Entry")

    def onButtonNewMap(self,event):
        temp = self.tbxNewMap.GetValue()
        pub.sendMessage("coord_listener", message=temp)
        #coordframe = CoordFrame(None,"Entry")
        self.coordframe.Show()

class CoordPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(CoordPanel, self).__init__(parent)
        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        pub.subscribe(self.coord_listener, "coord_listener")

        self.tbxNewMapNumber = wx.TextCtrl(self, id=1000, pos=(20,20), size = (50,20), style = wx.TE_CENTER|wx.TE_NOHIDESEL|wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        vsizer.Add(self.tbxNewMapNumber)
        
    def coord_listener(self, message):
        print(message)
        newmapnum = message
        self.tbxNewMapNumber.SetValue(newmapnum)
        self.tbxNewMapNumber.Refresh()


class GMDash(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.mainframe = MainFrame(parent = None, title = "Dashboard")
        self.mainframe.Show()
        return True

app = GMDash()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much  working as I hoped it would.

Comment: @Dadrick My pleasure. Welcome to SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers